# Jenkins: Use credentials in Pre-build shell

Tags: shell, svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the [pre-scm-buildstep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep) plugin to identify the SVN tag/branch version number to use in the SVN URL.  The way I'm doing this is with an `svn ls`.  The command throws an authentication error.  How can I use the stored global credential in the shell?

***Shell Commands***

```
SVN_V=`svn ls...` # need to use credential here
echo SVN_V=$SVN_V > build.properties
```

***Error***

```
Authentication realm: <http://mysvn.com:80> Subversion repository
Username: svn: OPTIONS of 'http://mysvn.com/path/to/branch': authorization failed (http://mysvn.com)
```